# Image Shifting when Webpage is Resized after Floating Left

Tags: html, css, image, resize

I have no idea why my image is shifting when my webpage is resized. There is no absolute positioning, the image just floats left, and the parents only give it some padding and margin.
Here is the HTML:

```css
.section-title {
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.section-title-info {
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.section-words-info {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 550;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.section-info {
  background-color: #706D9F;
  padding: 2em 1em;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.img-main {
  float: left;
  height: 12em;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-info container">
  <h2 class="section-title section-title-info">Information</h2>
  <img class="img-main" src="https://ibb.co/g7LnzSc">
  <span class="section-words-info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
 sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </span>
</section>
```

Comment: What are you expecting your image to do?

Comment: The image is coming out of the container, and out of line with the text. I want it to stay inline with the text and inside of the container.

Comment: Sorry the image doesn't show up in the code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `overflow: auto;` to your `.section-info` By using `float` it takes that element out of the flow of the document so you need to force the parent to include it by using overflow auto. See here:

```css
.section-title {
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.section-title-info {
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.section-words-info {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 550;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.section-info {
  background-color: #706D9F;
  padding: 2em 1em;
  overflow: auto;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.img-main {
  float: left;
  height: 12em;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-info container">
  <h2 class="section-title section-title-info">Information</h2>
  <img class="img-main" src="https://w3schools.com/html/img_girl.jpg" />
  <span class="section-words-info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
 sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </span>
</section>
```